# Managing multiple git commit email addresses

Tags: git, gitlab, commit, git-commit

I use my personal laptop for work (they are fine with it) but I have noticed that all my work commits use my personal email address. I don't want to default to my work email address globally on my machine for git, is there a way that when I commit I can have my personal email address for some repos and my work email for others?

I'm not bothered about rewriting the history on the existing commits, just moving forward.

Comment: You could set the email locally for that copy. Just set it like you would while in the repo folder, omitting the `--global` flag. `git config user.email your.work.email@domain.com`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can take advantage of `--local` settings to precisely manage what email each repo should use.

```
# to set your work email only for the current repo
git config --local user.email '<your work email>'

# to set an email globally, as a fallthrough if a repo doesn't have a local setting for user.email
git config --global user.email '<your personal email>'
```

Answer (score 5):

Another solution than the one provided by @RomainValeri is to use the "Conditional include" git feature (that I find more convenient because you don't have to forgot to set the email in each new repository --it is automatically applied if you create the repository in the good work or personal folder--)

You could put all your personal repositories in a specific folder (here `~/personal/`) and set the config so that when you use git, it will use a specific configuration for all the repositories inside this folder.

That way, you won't forget to set the personal settings when cloning or creating a new repository.

You could do it like that:

In `~/.gitconfig`

```
[user]
    name = John Doe
    email = john.doe@work-account.com

[includeIf "gitdir:~/personal/"]
    path = ~/personal/.gitconfig
```

In the new config file containing your personal information `~/personal/.gitconfig`:

```
[user]
    email = john.doe@personal-account.com
```

edit: reading again your question and because that's your personal computer, perhaps you would like to do the opposite, so you just have to switch both emails...